# Is it possible to port the XINU version for Intel Pentium Architecture onto Atmel AVR STK500?

Tags: operating-system, avr, porting, atmel, xinu

I am trying to work on Xinu and I wanted to know whether it would be possible for me to port the XINU written for Intel Pentium Architecture onto an Atmel AVR STK500 Development Board. It need not be that development board only. It can be any other development board also.

Thanks 
NB

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is possible because it [has been done before](http://sites.google.com/site/avrxinu/project-definition).